# Hudson Environment

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I would like to know how I can get the build number into a .txt file in Hudson

Under execute shell
echo $BUILD_NUMBER >> bldnum.txt

Is this right way?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on some version of Linux. On Windows, you'd want an Execute Batch task with

```
echo %BUILD_NUMBER% > bldnum.txt
```

(I'm assuming you don't want to append... Builds should be clear of dependencies on previous builds anyways)

Comment: echo $BUILD_NUMBER 2>&1 | tee bnum.txt works fine, Thanks anyways.. I tested it.:-)

Comment: FYI, %BUILD_NUMBER% is to Windows, what $BUILD_NUMBER is to Linux

Comment: @Sagar: Yep, that was the gist of my answer... I noted that at least one of sharp's previous questions involved a Windows Hudson slave and the job outlined in the question would fail miserably there.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the fyi was for sharp.